# Codeigniter: Email attachment of last emails not cleared while sending multiple emails in loop

Tags: php, email, attachment

My code sends multiple emails in loop with attachment,

Problem is attachments of last(previous all) emails get attached to next email.

ex. suppose 3 emails in database with 1 attachment in each(a1.pdf, a2.pdf, a3.pdf)
then, 
it sends email with attachment as

email 1:

attachment :a1.pdf

email 2:

attachment :a1.pdf, a2.pdf

email 3:

attachment :a1.pdf, a2.pdf, a3.pdf

**I am using codeigniter framework.**

My code is (this code is called in loop)

.
.
.

$this->email->subject($item->subject);

```
        $this->email->message($message);
        $attachments='';
        if(strlen($item->attachment) > 5)
        {
            $attachments = explode(',', $item->attachment);
            foreach($attachments as $attachment)
            {
                if(strlen($attachment)>5)
                $this->email->attach(FCPATH . 'attachments/' . $attachment);                    
            }                

        }

      $this->email->send();
```

.
.
.

Comment: found solution: $this->email->clear(TRUE);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `$this->email->clear();` to  clean out the variables set within the loop. [Read the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html).

Comment: Remember to include TRUE when calling clear() in order to remove any current attachments.

Answer (score 26):

You need to reset it in CodeIgniter.

At the end of the loop add:

```
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
```

This resets all email variables including the attachments, allowing you to create a new mail.

Comment: This works but in my case, it does not attached file on the last loop.

Comment: Upvoted as correct answer as clear() requires a TRUE boolean to clear the attachments.