# When sending automated emails with attachments sometimes files are duplicated

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, outlook, exchange-server

I am using the Codeigniter email class and sending automated emails when an invoice is created or something. I get the emails perfect fine on Gmail, no duplicate attachments but my clients who are using Exchange and Outlook are getting up to 3 duplicates of one file on the emails. Here is the relevant PHP code (however I do not think it is a code issue)

```
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.1and1.com',
            'smtp_port' => 25,
             //'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
            'smtp_user' =>'user@mywebsite.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'utf-8'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->clear();
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );
        $this->email->from('user@mywebsite', 'UserName');
        $this->email->to($email);  
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($msg);
        $this->email->attach($attachment);

        $this->email->send();
```

Any thoughts on why this might be occurring? I think it has something to do with the Outlook and Exchange server as I never get duplicates on my Gmail account

Thank you for looking

Comment: bit tricky, try few other email services and post results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem. Adding TRUE in clear solved the issue for me.

$this->email->clear(TRUE);

[Codeigniter: Email attachment of last emails not cleared while sending multiple emails in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050690/codeigniter-email-attachment-of-last-emails-not-cleared-while-sending-multiple)

Comment: This was indeed this issue, and this fixed it. Forgot to write my answer myself a couple of months ago ><

Answer (score 0):

What is **$this**? PHPMailer? A home grown lib? Something else?

Are you possibly looping through a list of addresses and maybe not creating a new message? (so email->attach is happening multiple times)?

Just guessing here.

Comment: Nope, one time send. Like I said I get the emails fine, Outlook and Exchange do not. $this is the codeigniter object reference so that is how everything is called

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the Codeigniter bit. Have you tried a var_dump just before the send? And have you checked the email headers?